# VHDLTestbench U(undefined) waveform result

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to run 2 bit Full_adder vhdl code for testbench but getting U(undefined) in the waveform simulation. Could you please advise?

**1 bit full adder**

```
 entity full_adder is
    Port ( A : in STD_LOGIC;
       B : in STD_LOGIC;
       Cin : in STD_LOGIC;
       S : out STD_LOGIC;
       Cout : out STD_LOGIC);
  end full_adder;

  architecture Behavioral of full_adder is

  begin
   S<=A xor B xor Cin;
   Cout<=(A and B)or(B and Cin)or(A and Cin);

   end Behavioral;
```

**2bit full adder**

```
    entity full_adder_2bit is
    Port ( A : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
       B : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
       Cin : in STD_LOGIC;
       S : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
       Cout : out STD_LOGIC);
end full_adder_2bit;


architecture Behavioral of full_adder_2bit is
Component full_adder
port(A : in STD_LOGIC;
       B : in STD_LOGIC;
       Cin : in STD_LOGIC;
       S : out STD_LOGIC;
        Cout : out STD_LOGIC);  
end component;
signal C:STD_LOGIC;   
begin
Bit_adder0: full_adder port map(A=>A(0),
                    B=>B(0),
                    Cin=>Cin,
                    S=>S(0),
                    Cout=>C);
 Bit_adder1:full_adder port map(A=>A(1),
                           B=>B(1),
                           Cin=>C,
                            S=>S(1),
                            Cout=>Cout);

 end Behavioral;
```

**2bit full adder testbench**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
entity full_adder_2bit_tb is  
--  Port ( );
end full_adder_2bit_tb;

architecture Behavioral of full_adder_2bit_tb is
component full_adder_2bit 
port( A : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
      B : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
      Cin : in STD_LOGIC;
      S : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
      Cout : out STD_LOGIC);
end component; 
constant Period: Time :=10ns;
signal A_tb: unsigned(1 downto 0):= (others=>'0');
signal B_tb:unsigned(1 downto 0):= (others => '0');
signal Cin_tb:STD_LOGIC;
signal S_tb: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
signal Cout_tb:STD_LOGIC;

begin
Bit_adder_tb0: full_adder_2bit port map
(A=>A_tb,B=>B_tb,Cin=>Cin_tb,S=>S_tb,Cout=>Cout_tb);

stim_proc: process
variable i,j :integer;
begin
for Cin in 0 to 1 loop
 for i in 0 to 2 loop
  for j in 0 to 2 loop
 A_tb <= to_unsigned(i,2); 
B_tb <= to_unsigned(j,2);
    wait for period;
end loop
end loop
end loop
wait;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: In your testbench your component full_adder_2bit will be unbound, the entity you have has A and B inputs that are std_logic_vector while your A_tb and B_tb are type unsigned. (I quit checking there).

Comment: I've modified the data type as below but still getting (U) in the simulation?

Comment: I've modified the data type as below but still getting (U) in   the  simulation?      
    signal A_tb: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0):= (others=>'0');    
    signal B_tb:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0):= (others => '0');
           
    A_tb <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(to_unsigned(i,2)); 
     B_tb <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(to_unsigned(j,2));

Comment: Fold your corrections into your code in the question, add the missing context clauses for full_adder and full_adder_2bit, in the testbench put a space between the numeric literal and unit name in the physical literal in the constant period and drive cin_tb. You'll get a non-'U's output.  (With carry in 'U', what will an adder do?)

Comment: All three of the end statements for loops in process stim_process are missing the semicolon after loop in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your testbench has the following defects:

1. None of the nested loop statements assign cin_tb which is used as an actual in the port map for full_adder_2bit. This results in undefined outputs during simulation (The declaration for Cin_tb does not include an initial value, the default is 'U'). Adder outputs are dependent on the cin input.
2. The physical literal for the constant Period is missing a space between the numeric literal and unit name as required in the VHDL standard. (And yes there is a commercial simulator that allows this. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 15.3 Lexical elements, separators, and delimiters paragraph 4.)
3. In process stim_proc the variables i and j are not used.  Loop statements with a For iteration scheme implicitly declare their iterators.
   See 10.10 Loop statement paragraph 7.)
4. The three end statements for the three loop statements are all missing the following semicolon statement separator. (See 10.10 Loop statement paragraph 2.)
5. the first second two loop statements only cover three of the four possible binary values for A_tb and B_tb.

These depend on your commented changes to the declarations for A_tb and B_tb switching to type std_logic_vector from type unsigned and the change to their assignment in the inner loop statement adding a type conversion from the result of to_unsigned to std_logic_vector. These changes have not been introduced in to your question at the time of this writing.

Fixing those and your code looks something like:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity full_adder_2bit_tb is  
 --  port ( );
end entity full_adder_2bit_tb;

architecture behavioral of full_adder_2bit_tb is
    component full_adder_2bit 
        port (
            a:      in  std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
            b:      in  std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
            cin:    in  std_logic;
            s:      out std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
            cout:   out std_logic
          );
    end component; 
    constant period: time := 10 ns;  -- was missing space in physical literal
    -- types of a_tb and b_tb were unsigned, now std_logic_vector
    signal a_tb:     std_logic_vector (1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal b_tb:     std_logic_vector (1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal cin_tb:   std_logic := '0';  -- foolish consistency
    signal s_tb:     std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    signal cout_tb:  std_logic;

begin

bit_adder_tb0: 
    full_adder_2bit 
        port map (
            a => a_tb,
            b => b_tb,
            cin => cin_tb, 
            s => s_tb,
            cout=>cout_tb
        );

stim_proc: 
    process
    --     variable i, j:  integer; -- NOT USED 
    --     loop iterators implicitly declared
    begin        
        -- can assign cin directly to cin_tb:
        for cin in std_ulogic'('0') to std_ulogic'('1') loop
            -- The qualified expressions describe which '0' and '1' enums
            -- the loop iterator cin implicit declaration defines a subtype
            -- of std_ulogic, the base type of std_logic
            for i in 0 to 3 loop  -- was to 3, cover all binary values
                for j in 0 to 3 loop  -- ditto
                    a_tb <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(i, 2)); 
                    b_tb <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(j, 2));
                    cin_tb <= cin;  -- Drive cin_tb 
                    wait for period;
                end loop;  -- Missing semicolon
            end loop;  -- Missing semicolon
        end loop;  -- Missing semicolon
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture behavioral;
```

Note that the outer loop iterator has a subtype of type unsigned, allowing cin to be directly assigned to Cin_tb.  The testbench has been formatted for readability, adding optional reserved words and whitespace. Style is generally either personal or organizational and not defined by the VHDL standard.

The essential change to overcome and undefined waveform result is driving Cin_tb. The above changes result in outputs with clear logic levels:

[image: full_adder_2bit_tb_fixed.png]